# Bash: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I do this in a script:

```
read direc <<< $(basename `pwd`)
```

and I get:

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

in an ubuntu machine

```
/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.0.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

while I do not get this error in another suse machine:

```
/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Why the error?

Comment: FYI, context is very important. Find the name of program running a script try `grep PPid /proc/self/status | sed -E 's/^(PPid:\s*)(.*)$/\/proc\/\2\/exe/'`. to display what shell terminal is running try `echo $0`

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Does your script reference `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` in its hash bang line? The default system shell in Ubuntu is [dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), not [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), so if you have `#!/bin/sh` then your script will be using a different shell than you expect. Dash does not have the `<<<` redirection operator.

Make sure the shebang line is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

And run the script with:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Do *not* run it with an explicit `sh` as that will ignore the shebang:

```
$ sh ./script.sh   # Don't do this!
```

Comment: I have "#!/bin/bash" on top the sh file, but it still gives that error. It worked when used bash ./script.sh as @chris's said.

Comment: @ibilgen Are you running it with `sh ./script.sh`? Don't run scripts with an explicit shell. Just type the script name `./script.sh` so it can use the interpreter declared in the shebang line.

Comment: Should I change default shell `dash` to `bash`?

Comment: @kittygirl I just changed from '/bin/sh' to '/bin/bash' and it worked!!

Comment: No, don't change the default shell. This is a bug in the script / how the script is run. [Don't make global changes to fix a local problem.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873)

Answer (score 40):

If you're using the following to run your script:

```
sudo sh ./script.sh
```

Then you'll want to use the following instead:

```
sudo bash ./script.sh
```

The reason for this is that Bash is not the default shell for Ubuntu. So, if you use "sh" then it will just use the default shell; which is actually Dash. This will happen regardless if you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script. As a result, you will need to explicitly specify to use `bash` as shown above, and your script should run at expected.

Dash doesn't support redirects the same as Bash.

Answer (score 24):

### Docker:

I was getting this problem from my Dockerfile as I had:

```
RUN bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)
```

However, according to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/7489/files), it was solved:

> The ***exec*** form makes it possible to avoid shell string munging, and
>   to `RUN`  commands using a base image that does not contain `/bin/sh`.
>
> #### Note
>
> To use a different shell, other than `/bin/sh`, use the ***exec*** form
>   passing in the desired shell. For example,
>
> ```
> RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello"]
> ```

---

### Solution:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)"]
```

*Notice the quotes around **each** parameter.*

Comment: This made it possible for me to get the [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) running inside a Dockerfile. That here-string was needed for saying "yes" (y) to an "overwrite question" (not important: it was for `ssh-keygen -q -t rsa  <<< ""$'\n'"y"`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43235320/11154841).

Comment: Before RUN set `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` and then all following RUN commands will be bash shell instead of sh.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the output of that command and put it in a variable. then use `heredoc`. for example:

```
nc -l -p 80 <<< "tested like a charm";
```

can be written like:

```
nc -l -p 80 <<EOF
tested like a charm
EOF
```

and like this (this is what you want):

```
text="tested like a charm"
nc -l -p 80 <<EOF
$text
EOF
```

Practical example in `busybox` under `docker` container:

```
kasra@ubuntu:~$ docker run --rm -it busybox
/ # nc -l -p 80 <<< "tested like a charm";
sh: syntax error: unexpected redirection


/ # nc -l -p 80 <<EOL
> tested like a charm
> EOL
^Cpunt!       => socket listening, no errors. ^Cpunt! is result of CTRL+C signal.


/ # text="tested like a charm"
/ # nc -l -p 80 <<EOF
> $text
> EOF
^Cpunt!
```

Comment: ...or `echo 'text' | nc` which is even shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the work-around. On MacOS you have to do `\. /dev/stdin <<< "$(wget -qO- https://...myscript.sh)"` to successfully source a remote script with the current function arguments and import its functions to the local terminal. Your solution made it POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

do it the simpler way,

```
direc=$(basename `pwd`)
```

Or use the shell

```
$ direc=${PWD##*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to the error may be if you are running a cron job that updates a subversion working copy and then has attempted to run a versioned script that was in a conflicted state after the update...

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, if I run a script directly, the default is `bash`.

If I run it with `sudo`, the default is `sh`.

That’s why I was hitting this problem when I used `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case error is because i have put ">>" twice

```
mongodump --db=$DB_NAME --collection=$col --out=$BACKUP_LOCATION/$DB_NAME-$BACKUP_DATE >> >> $LOG_PATH
```

i just correct it as

```
mongodump --db=$DB_NAME --collection=$col --out=$BACKUP_LOCATION/$DB_NAME-$BACKUP_DATE >> $LOG_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running the script, you should check first line of the shell script for the interpreter.

Eg: 
if scripts starts with /bin/bash , run the script using the below command 
"bash script_name.sh"

if script starts with /bin/sh, run the script using the below command
"sh script_name.sh"

./sample.sh - This will detect the interpreter from the first line of the script and run.

Different Linux distributions having different shells as default.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: Don't you think that I explained the solution here with an example?

Comment: Is there anything here that isn't adequately covered in [John Kugelman's answer](/a/2462357) written 8 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: `#!/bin/bash`
Point 2: Make sure your file have suitable permissions (for a sample sh file, `chmod 777 test.sh`)
Point 3: `./test.sh`, don't use `sh test.sh`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably chmod 755) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges.