# Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I ran a deployment script to setup my server as root. Then I tried to run another script called test.sh which had the following lines in it:

```
# Logging
exec  > >(tee -a /var/log/test_full.log)
exec 2> >(tee -a /var/log/test_error.log)
```

However when I try this I get the following error:

```
test.sh: 19: test.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

What might be causing this issue do you think? I've not heard of this error before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462357/1906307) solves your problem, assuming that your script snippet is complete.

In brief, you are running your script through `dash`, not `bash`. The solution is as simple as adding the necessary `#!/bin/bash`

What a system runs by default if the `#!` is missing varies from system to system. On my system, I don't get your error because a shell that understands your redirections is run by default. I've had to simulate the case where `dash` would be the default shell to reproduce your error.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to be a pain but both files start with #!/bin/bash

Comment: Fact: when I run your ``test.sh`` script as ``bash test.sh`` there's no error, but when I run it with ``dash test.sh`` I get the exact error you get. For whatever reason exists on your system, it's not ``bash`` that is executing your script.

Comment: Ah, it's because I ran it "sh test.sh" I think!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you run your script with `./myscript`, make sure your scripts starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and not `#!/bin/sh` or anything else. The error suggests that another shell than Bash is used.

If your script indeed do, check that `/bin/bash` is not a symbolic link and that it indeed is Bash with `/bin/bash --version` .

Comment: As above, both files start with #!/bin/bash

Comment: What does `/bin/bash --version` output?

Comment: Thank you for the help but I solved it with both your helps and could only pick one answer im afraid but I hope the upvote helps :)

Comment: Fair enough, @Louis' comment was probably the element that led to solving the case. +1 for his answer and +1 for your question :)

Comment: +1 I've been in an environment where `/bin/bash` was a symbolic link to `busybox`, meaning the shell was `ash` and not `bash`...