# running bash script as sudo, 'Syntax error: redirection unexpected'

Tags: linux, bash

Running the following script as myself works but not when I use `sudo`. As you can probably tell, the `touch` error is just to make sure something is written to the log file.

```
dave@pi1:~ $ ./test.sh
touch: cannot touch '/asdf/asdf/asdf': No such file or directory  <--- As expected
dave@pi1:~ $ sudo ./test.sh
./test.sh: 2: ./test.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected  <--- why this not work?
dave@pi1:~ $
```

The script:

```
LOG_FILE=/var/log/usbhook
exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} )
exec 2> >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} >&2)

touch /asdf/asdf/asdf
```

The aim is to have a script fired when I plug in a USB stick so I'm assuming it should work when ran using sudo.

Comment: Add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as first line in your script

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Comment: // , Do you have a specific question to ask, or more of a "this is what I expect it to do, can you help debug my code?"

Comment: // , Also, welcome to the weird and wonderful world of shell scripting. Here be dragons.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: it was a long time ago. @TedTrippin please consider + accept VodkaBottle answer. `echo $0` returns the terminal's shell (also `sudo echo $0`). and `grep PPid /proc/self/status | sed -E 's/^(PPid:\s*)(.*)$/\/proc\/\2\/exe/'` returns the program running the current script.

Comment: There's no need to call yourself a "noob".

Comment: @dank8, $0 is not reliably the shell name. It can be the script name, it can be a completely arbitrary string passed at the beginning of argv, etc.

Comment: And this **is** like the duplicate: `>(` is a syntax element that can't be used in sh. Just because one operator is `>( )` and the other is `<<<` doesn't make it two different questions; it's the same misunderstanding about what it takes to ensure that bash-only syntax is available.

Answer (score 1):

[Bash: Syntax error: redirection unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462317/bash-syntax-error-redirection-unexpected)

^Similar, and might answer your question. From the accepted answer in that thread:

"The default system shell in Ubuntu is dash, not bash, so if you have #!/bin/sh then your script will be using a different shell than you expect. Dash does not have the <<< redirection operator."

Comment: I don't believe that's the same. That's about a particular operator which isn't supported on a different Linux flavour

Comment: // , I agree with Ted that although the _solutions_ might be the same (add a shebang, noob!) the _questions_ could be different. Ted, what's different about your question?

Comment: We don't care if the questions are different, actually. This is a duplicate because the answer is the same. We would have mountains of duplicates if we would allow every minor variation of a basic problem to be a new question. This is bad for the site because then nobody can find the right one in the haystack of very similar questions.